# Reference type of expression with Golang

Tags: go

I have this

```
var Map = map[string]Model{}

var (
    mtx    sync.Mutex
    people Map
)
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

Is there any way of referencing the type of the Map, something like this:

```
var (
    mtx    sync.Mutex
    people reflect.Type(Map)  // <<< ?
)
```

or should I just resort to declare the type like so:

```
type Map map[string]Model
```

and the initializing the map like I do on line 54? I was just trying to initialize the map in the file without having to do it in the Init func.

Comment: The way you're using `Map` is as a type, so yes, you should declare it as a type. You can't use `reflect` to get the type of some other object to use when declaring a variable (although if you assign the new variable to that other object in the declaration, it will be of the same type).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use something like

```
type Model struct{}
type ModelMap map[string]Model

var (
    mtx sync.Mutex
    people = ModelMap{}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map literal to initialize map:

```
type Model struct {}

var people = map[string]Model{
    "Foo": Model{},
    "Bar":   Model{},
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understood your problem but you can do something like this:

```
 var Map = map[string]Model{}

 var (
   mtx sync.Mutex
   people = Map
 )
```

That way `people` is initialized as same as `Map`.